# "Encrypt contents to secure data" is grayed out even after regedit dword is set to 0

Tags: windows, windows-10, encryption, regedit

My `Encrypt contents to secure data` is grayed out on my computer.

I have already gone:

- Into the regedit and set `NtfsDisableEncrypton` to 0 and rebooted.
- To `Admin Tools` > `System` in `Control Panel` and set `Encrypting File System (EFS)` to `Automatic` in start up. I have rebooted after this.

The checkbox is still grayed out! Can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried running the command, in addition to the reg key? `fsutil behavior set disableencryption 0`. Also, that reg key is supposed to occur in several places. have you changed them all? http://www.technipages.com/disable-windows-file-encryption-efs

Comment: @FrankThomas Sorry for the late reply. I just tried entering that command in cmd with admin and rebooted. 

`Encrypt contents to secure data` is still grayed out. Do you have anymore ideas how to fix this?

Comment: If you're running Windows 10 Home Edition, [EFS encryption is not available.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/how-to-enable-grayed-out-encrypt-contents-to/c10c086a-a2d1-44f8-a330-3009eb176d30)